# Предупреждение "unresolved import"

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, pip

Я установил через pip библиотеку vk_api и в коде указал "import vk_api", но выдает предупреждение "unresolved import". Я так понимаю, программа не видит библиотеку. Как это решаемо? Прошу максимально подробное описание.

Comment: вот, что-то похожее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939751/pylint-unresolved-import-error-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Могли установить не для того интерпретатора. Воспользуйтесь для установки python -m pip install vk_api

Comment: @Denis640Kb  Попробовал, но в итоге вышли строчки с "Requirement already satisfied: ...", видимо, всё верно установлено

Comment: @user321409 тогда уточните, подключена только эта одна библиотека? Можете выложить пример? (Шапку кода с импортами) И в чём работаете с кодом.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Подключена только эта библиотека, вот первые три строки кода:

`import vk_api

from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll

from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotEventType`

Использую Visual Studio 2019

Comment: @user321409 если не поможет import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType то надо создавать .env

Comment: @Denis640Kb Не помогло. А какую программу посоветуете использовать для создания env файла?

Comment: Перейдите в папку рабочей области (здесь workspaceRootFolder) и создайте файл .env
В этом пустом файле .env добавьте строку PYTHONPATH = codeFolder (замените codeFolder на имя вашей папки)
Добавьте "python.envFile": "$ {workspaceFolder} /. Env" в файл settings.json.
Перезапустите код VS

Comment: @user321409 чтобы не засорять, давайте продожим в чате. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102517/discussion-between-user321409-and-denis640kb